# How do I wrap a set of items within <xml:choose>?

Tags: xslt

A `<div>` cannot be a child of `<xml:choose>`, but I only want `<li>`s to repeat — in other words, not their parent `<div>`s or `<ul>`s.

Below you'll find my sample input, XSLT, and sample desired output.

### Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Collection>
      <Content>
        <Html>
          <root>
            <news>
              <title>Item 1</title>
              <publication-date>2010-04-16</publication-date>
              <article-content>
                <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
              </article-content>
            </news>
          </root>
        </Html>
      </Content>
      <Content>
        <Html>
          <root>
            <news>
              <title>Item 2</title>
              <publication-date>2010-04-19</publication-date>
              <article-content>
                <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
              </article-content>
            </news>
          </root>
        </Html>
      </Content>
    </Collection>
```

### XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
      <xsl:template match="/Collection/Content" xml:space="preserve">
        <div id="latest-news" class="module clear">
          <h2>Latest News</h2>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
              <div id="featured-story">
                <h3>
                  <a href="#tk">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/title/node()" />
                  </a>
                </h3>
                <p class="publish-date">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/publication-date/node()" />
                </p>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/article-content/node()" />
                <p class="more">
                  <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position() &gt; 1 and position() &lt; 6">
              <div id="summaries" class="column-1">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <h3>
                      <a href="#tk">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/title/node()" />
                      </a>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="publish-date">
                      <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/publication-date/node()" />
                    </p>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/article-content/node()" />
                    <p class="more">
                      <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
                    </p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <div id="links" class="column-2">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <p class="publish-date">
                      <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/publication-date/node()" />
                    </p>
                    <h3>
                      <a href="#tk">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/title/node()" />
                      </a>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="more">
                      <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
                    </p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output

```
<div id="latest-news" class="module clear">
    <h2>Latest News</h2>
    <div id="featured-story">
        <h3><a href="#tk">[Item 1]</a></h3>
        <p class="publish-date">July 7, 2010</p>
        <p>[Article content, in form of an extended summary]</p>
        <p class="more">
            <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="summaries" class="column-1">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="#tk">[Item 2]</a></h3>
                <p class="publish-date">July 7, 2010</p>
                <p>[Article content, in short summary format]</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="#tk">[Item 3 and so on]</a></h3>
                <p class="publish-date">July 7, 2010</p>
                <p>[Article content, in short summary format]</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="links" class="column-2">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="#tk">[Item 6]</a></h3>
                <p class="publish-date">July 7, 2010</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="#tk">[Item 7 and so on]</a></h3>
                <p class="publish-date">July 7, 2010</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, provide input sample and desired output in order to help you. Otherwise, we were only guessing.

Comment: @Alejandro: Jim is very close below. Should I go ahead and still add samples as requested?

Comment: Sometimes there is going to be someone who will try to guess, but most times there isn't. XSLT declare the "bindings" between an input and an output. So, it's dificult to debug a stylesheet without them. For example: there are a lot XPath into your stylesheet wich end with `node()` node test that make me think you want its string value. Well, you don't need it with `value-of`, but without input source I'm guessing.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks, I've added this information and will make sure to include more information going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is wrong.  Here's a syntactically valid (but untested) refactoring.  I didn't test since you didn't post some input XML, but I think this is what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Collection" xml:space="preserve">
      <div id="latest-news" class="module clear">

        <h2>Latest News</h2>
        <div id="featured-story">
          <h3>
            <a href="#tk">
              <xsl:copy-of select="Content[1]/Html/root/news/title/node()"/>
            </a>
          </h3>
          <p class="publish-date">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Content[1]/Html/root/news/publication-date/node()"/>
          </p>
          <xsl:copy-of select="Content[1]/Html/root/news/article-content/node()"/>
          <p class="more">
            <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div id="summaries" class="column-1">
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Content[position() &gt; 1 and position() &lt; 6]"/>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="links" class="column-2">
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Content[position() &gt; 5]"/>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Content" xml:space="preserve">
    <li>
      <h3>
        <a href="#tk">
          <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/title/node()"/>
        </a>
      </h3>
      <p class="publish-date">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/publication-date/node()"/>
      </p>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Html/root/news/article-content/node()"/>
      <p class="more">
        <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Jim, thanks!  
When you wrote "wrong", did you mean inefficient? Or something else entirely? This is my first attempt at XSLT, so I'm doing my best to learn best practices now.  
And, as for your solution, it gets me very close. I intended for `#links` to not include `article-content`, but this is but a minor quibble. Thanks again!

Comment: Your structure could never be used to accommodate your requirement that only the `<li>` tags repeat.  Analyze the difference between yours and mine and you'll see what was needed.  If you want to specialize the `Content` template, read up on the `mode=` parameter (on both `template` and `apply-templates) to set up two variants that output different HTML.

Comment: Also BTW, if the answer works for you it's customary to "accept" it by clicking the check mark at the left of the answer.

Comment: Accepted. I'll look into the `mode` parameter now. Thanks!

Comment: And, following up, `mode` worked perfectly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction there.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="Collection">
        <div id="latest-news" class="module clear">
            <h2>Latest News</h2>
            <div id="featured-story">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Content[1]"/>
            </div>
            <div id="summaries" class="column-1">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Content[position() > 1 and 6 > position()]"/>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="links" class="column-2">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Content[position() > 5]"/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Content[position() != 1]">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="news">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <p class="more">
            <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Content[position() > 5]/*/*/news">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title|publication-date" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <h3>
            <a href="#tk">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </a>
        </h3>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="publication-date">
        <p class="publish-date">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article-content">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,15)" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Content[1]/*/*/*/article-content">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<Collection>
    <Content>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <news>
                    <title>Item 1</title>
                    <publication-date>2010-04-13</publication-date>
                    <article-content>
                        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
                    </article-content>
                </news>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <news>
                    <title>Item 2</title>
                    <publication-date>2010-04-14</publication-date>
                    <article-content>
                        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
                    </article-content>
                </news>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <news>
                    <title>Item 3</title>
                    <publication-date>2010-04-15</publication-date>
                    <article-content>
                        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
                    </article-content>
                </news>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <news>
                    <title>Item 4</title>
                    <publication-date>2010-04-16</publication-date>
                    <article-content>
                        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
                    </article-content>
                </news>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <news>
                    <title>Item 5</title>
                    <publication-date>2010-04-17</publication-date>
                    <article-content>
                        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
                    </article-content>
                </news>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <news>
                    <title>Item 6</title>
                    <publication-date>2010-04-18</publication-date>
                    <article-content>
                        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
                    </article-content>
                </news>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <news>
                    <title>Item 7</title>
                    <publication-date>2010-04-19</publication-date>
                    <article-content>
                        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
                    </article-content>
                </news>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
</Collection>
```

Result:

```
<div id="latest-news" class="module clear">
    <h2>Latest News</h2>
    <div id="featured-story">
        <h3>
            <a href="#tk">Item 1</a>
        </h3>
        <p class="publish-date">2010-04-13</p>
        <p>Aliquam mollis porttitor auctor. Aenean laoreet justo sed ipsum lobortis eleifend. In ac mollis neque. Donec rutrum turpis vel quam mattis eu vestibulum arcu tincidunt.</p>
        <p class="more">
            <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="summaries" class="column-1">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#tk">Item 2</a>
                </h3>
                <p class="publish-date">2010-04-14</p>
                <p>Aliquam mollis </p>
                <p class="more">
                    <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#tk">Item 3</a>
                </h3>
                <p class="publish-date">2010-04-15</p>
                <p>Aliquam mollis </p>
                <p class="more">
                    <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#tk">Item 4</a>
                </h3>
                <p class="publish-date">2010-04-16</p>
                <p>Aliquam mollis </p>
                <p class="more">
                    <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#tk">Item 5</a>
                </h3>
                <p class="publish-date">2010-04-17</p>
                <p>Aliquam mollis </p>
                <p class="more">
                    <a href="#tk">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="links" class="column-2">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#tk">Item 6</a>
                </h3>
                <p class="publish-date">2010-04-18</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#tk">Item 7</a>
                </h3>
                <p class="publish-date">2010-04-19</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: This way you get exactly what you want. "Pattern matching" your input in your templates you can express better your desired output and add possibility of reusability and maintenance.

**Edit**: Minor change in order to emphasize "pattern matching".

Comment: This is great. In addition to the reusablility you've factored in, I also see a couple new (to me) features I can start utilizing, such as: `/*`, for wildcards; and `substring(.,1,15)`, for string selection. Thanks!